# how to change an icon behavior in WPF?

Tags: wpf, icons

I want to change the behavior of the icon in my WPF mainwindow. I already know how to change it looks - setting the icon to an ImageSource as I want. What I wish to accomplish is that when clicking on the icon a custom menu of my own will open, and not the standard Open / Close / Minimize options.

Any ideas?

Comment: I think there is no simple solution. I can tell one. We need to create the your own template window, and set its `Image` with `TextBlock`. We get title with icon. Then set the handler for the image (MouseLeftButtonDown), which will open the `ContextMenu` with your commands.

Comment: @Tal Malaki, are you in Windows 7?

Comment: No, i am in Windows 2008, and visual studio 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Place this code inside your WPF window. You may have to adjust the code a little, but it's roughtly what you are asking for. It works only for right click on the icon. If you need left click use `WM_NCLBUTTONDOWN` as the message.

It works by intercepting native Windowing messages on current window. WM_NC* messages are responsible for communicating window chrome event. Once you intercept the events, you just need to display context menu in correct position.

```
    protected override void OnSourceInitialized(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSourceInitialized(e);
        HwndSource source = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this) as HwndSource;
        source.AddHook(WndProc);
    }

    private IntPtr WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)
    {
        if (msg == 0xA4) //WM_NCRBUTTONDOWN  
        {
            //Screen position of clicked point
            var pos = new Point(lParam.ToInt32() & 0xffff, lParam.ToInt32() >> 16);

            //Check if we clicked an icon these values are not precise
            // and could be adjusted
            if ((pos.X - Left < 20) && (pos.Y - Top < 20))
            {
                //Open up context menu, should be replaced with reference to your
                // own ContextMenu object
                var context = new ContextMenu();
                var item = new MenuItem { Header = "Test" };
                context.Items.Add(item);
                item.Click += (o,e) => MessageBox.Show("Hello World!");

                //Those are important properties to set
                context.Placement = PlacementMode.AbsolutePoint;
                context.VerticalOffset = pos.Y;
                context.HorizontalOffset = pos.X;
                context.IsOpen = true;

                handled = true;
            }
        }

        return IntPtr.Zero;
    }
```

Comment: OK, but what if I want that pressing on the word Test will invoke an event?

Comment: @Tal Malaki Just add item handler to MenuItem, like you would in standard WPF menu. See my edited answer for example.